# Remove Dom Element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I try to remove a div out of the dom-tree with jquery in a play application like this:

```
<form class="form-search">
    <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="@Messages.get("frontend.wiki.search.placeholder")">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton" onclick="search()">@Messages.get("frontend.wiki.search")</button>
</form>

@* most read articles *@
<div class="row" id="mostread">
    @components.wikitable(Messages.get("frontend.wiki.mostread"), WikiArticle.findAllMostReadArticles(5))
</div>

.....

<script type="text/javascript">
    var search = function() {
        $('#mostread').empty();
    }
</script>
```

The "mostread" part on the page disappears for one second when I click the button but everything is back as it was afterwards. Why is that? Using bootstrap too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping your button type as "submit", you can keep it as just "button" so now it should be

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton" onclick="search()">@Messages.get("frontend.wiki.search")</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) for that if you plan to reinsert it later:

```
var elem = $('#mostread').detach();
```

In case you don't care reinserting, just use remove():

```
$('#mostread').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the button type. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2292163/adiya helped!